# How can I get rid of this ugly bumps

Tags: modeling

I was practicing with modeling and I created a bunch of light bulbs but they all have these really ugly bumps on the top of them.

If anyone has a solution to fix this, It would be very much appreciated if you could help.

[image]

Comment: Those "ugly bumps" are caused by a triangle mesh at the top of the object. Triangles sometimes don't transition so well when mixed with a subsurf modifier. You need to turn those triangles into quads.

Comment: For most cases use rounded cube is better than use sphere. You can enable it by enable "Extra objects" addons in "Add Mesh Category"